# How to get a mock & PDO working with PHPUnit on a SQL INSERT statement

Tags: php, sql, pdo, phpunit

I have a test class, called `ip_requestTest.php` which has the following function:

```
public function testSetTimestampCount()
    {

        $validData = [
            'id' => '99',
            'ip' => '127.0.0.1',
            'timestamp' => '2021-06-03 10:28:43.000'
        ];
        $table = 'ip';

        $stmt = $this->createMock(\PDOStatement::class);
        $stmt->expects($this->once())
            ->method('execute')
            ->with($validData)
            ->willReturn(true);

        global $pdo;
        $pdo = $this->createMock('PDO');
        $pdo->expects($this->once())
            ->method('prepare')
            ->with("INSERT INTO {$table} id,address,timestamp VALUES (:ip, :id, :timestamp)")
            ->willReturn($stmt);

        $ipStmt = new ip_request();
        $ipStmt->setTimestampCount($validData);

    }
```

Now the last line is the problem, `$ipStmt->setTimestampCount($validData);`

My actual setTimestampCount() function doesn't take just one parameter.

It looks like this:

```
    function setTimestampCount($ip,$id,$conn)
    {

        $query = $conn->prepare ("INSERT INTO `ip` (`id`, `address` ,`timestamp`)VALUES (:id,:ip,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)");
        $query ->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $query ->bindValue(':ip', $ip, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->execute();

    }
```

Can anyone help, or give me any clues as to how I can have this function being tested properly?

How do I include the data into the testing function call?

Thanks

UPDATE 1:

Tried the suggestion of the splat operator, and also removed timestamp insertion, as this can be done automatically by inserting the data.

Still not working, the error i get is
`Too few arguments to function 2 passed, exactly 3 expected.`
I know what this menas obviously, but how does the splat operator deal with this? if at all?

Comment: And what do you want to test here?

Comment: The setTimestampCount() function thanks, but like i explained, that takes 3 parameters, one of which is the actual connection, and also id, and ip, yet i can't seem to figure out how to pass these variables during the test, rather than the array $validData, which is what i want to be able to pass as part of the test.

Comment: With splat operator `...` it is `$ipStmt->setTimestampCount(...$validData);`

Comment: Tried that, and gave an update, still not working when I use that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method `setTimestampCount($ip,$id,$conn)` expects those 3 parameters.

The 3 you're passing in are the contents of `$validData`, i.e.

```
'id' => '99',
'ip' => '127.0.0.1',
'timestamp' => '2021-06-03 10:28:43.000'
```

Instead you need to get rid of the timestamp argument from that array, and replace it with your mocked connection.

Secondly, you're doing this:

```
$stmt->expects($this->once())
        ->method('execute')
        ->with($validData)
        ->willReturn(true);
```

However the `execute` method takes no arguments:

```
$query->execute();
```

It also doesn't return anything (or at least you're not assigning anything it returns to a variable), so there's no need to do `->willReturn(true);`

So the above should just be:

```
$stmt->expects($this->once())
        ->method('execute');
```

There's also no point testing the timestamp.  All you should be doing is checking the string you're passing into the `prepare` method.  So you need to check two strings look identical.  Currently the string you're testing is:

```
"INSERT INTO `ip` (`id`, `address` ,`timestamp`)VALUES (:id,:ip,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)"
```

And you're specifying

```
"INSERT INTO {$table} id,address,timestamp VALUES (:ip, :id, :timestamp)
```

So things like the missing `(`, `)`, the difference in spacing between arguments etc, will all cause this test to fail.  They need to be identical.

Finally, you're not actually testing whatever the `ip` and `id` or timestamp values are.  The `prepare` statement doesn't actually use them; it just has the string `:id,:ip,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

You should also really test the `bindValue` method, which does use the ip and id values.  That's slightly more complicated by the fact you're calling it twice, however you can use [PHPUnit's `withConsecutive` method](https://phpunit.de/manual/6.5/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.mock-objects.examples.with-consecutive.php) to handle this:

```
$stmt->expects($this->exactly(2))
     ->method('bindValue')
     ->withConsecutive(
         [':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT],
         [':ip', $ip, PDO::PARAM_STR]
     );
```

So I'd say the method should look like:

```
public function testSetTimestampCount()
{
    $table = 'ip';
    $id = '99';
    $ip => '127.0.0.1';
    
    $stmt = $this->createMock(\PDOStatement::class);
    $stmt->expects($this->once())
        ->method('execute');
        
    $stmt->expects($this->exactly(2))
        ->method('bindValue')
        ->withConsecutive(
             [':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT],
             [':ip', $ip, PDO::PARAM_STR]
        );
        
    $pdo = $this->createMock('PDO');
    $pdo->expects($this->once())
        ->method('prepare')
        ->with("INSERT INTO `ip` (`id`, `address` ,`timestamp`)VALUES (:id,:ip,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)")
        ->willReturn($stmt);
        
    $validData = [
        'id' => $id,
        'ip' => $ip,
        'conn' => $pdo
    ];

    $ipStmt = new ip_request();
    $ipStmt->setTimestampCount(...$validData);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @duncan, that explanation really helped clarify everything, and it now works perfectly, thanks for helping confirm the different parts.